# Nested Routing WIthout Type-Hinting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

Here are some of my routes;

```
Route::resource('surveys', 'Admins\SurveyController');
Route::resource('surveys.groups', 'Admins\Survey\GroupController');
Route::resource('surveys.groups.questions', 'Admins\Survey\Group\QuestionController');
```

But in order to use `index()` on `QuestionController` I have to have my QuestionController.php file something like;

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admins\Survey\GroupController;
use App\Models\Group;
use App\Models\Survey;

class QuestionController extends GroupController
{
    public function index(Survey $survey, Group $group)
    {
        //
    }
```

For a route like; `admins/surveys/1/group/1/questions`

This doesn't seem ideal. Is there a design pattern or particular method here to get around having to type-hint both `Survey` and `Group` right there?

If I'm extending from `GroupController` can I use that somehow?

Comment: What is the problem with having to typehint group and survey in the QuestionController@index?

Comment: just seems verbose and a lot repeating. especially when I add in an AnswerOptionController. I'll have to type-hint Survey, Group and Question on that one. When I am repeating myself so much - I figure I must be overlooking something.

Comment: These are just arguments of a method, there is no other way to use them otherwise. I don't think this a situation where you can avoid repeating them, but I'll follow the question in case someone suggest another way.

Comment: @TheFallen to be fair, I thought that Rails "automatically" resolved this for you. So that you would get an error if you tried to visit a Group show method with an id that didn't belong to the Survey object. Looks like I was wrong about that. So might just have to live with this.